# How to force Intellij IDEA to download JavaDoc

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I've specified URLs to documentation of libraries I use in my project, and every time I want to check the documentation, it downloads it from the internet.

I have a JAR with full JavaDoc locally.

Should I specify this JAR file, or force IDEA to download all docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Attach the jar file](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-library-and-global-library-pages.html) with the documentation to the library.